# android device rssi

Tags: android, bluetooth, rssi

I want to get individual bluetooth rssi value.

```
device1 address 00:00:00:00:00:01 rssi1
device2 address 00:00:00:00:00:02 rssi2
```

how can I get rssi1 and rssi2 value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discovering a device, use the `EXTRA_RSSI` parameter with the `ACTION_FOUND` intent, like so:

```
private BroadcastReceiver mBluetoothDeviceFoundReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Object rssi = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI);
    ...
```

Not sure about the return data type, so I just used `Object` in the example.